# How To Get Files Off a HTC M7 That Won't Stay On

Tags: backup, data-recovery, htc-one, bugs

I have a HTC One M7 that I need to get all the (~1GB) files off. The problem is that the phone restarts after about 10-30sec, so I don't have time to manually copy the files.

Phone Info:

- USB debugging is enabled
- the phone is not rooted

The phone restarts even while fast charging and re-calibrating the battery did not help.

I then attempted to download the files to my computer while the phone was off/in recovery mode. The phone is detected in recovery mode on Windows, but I can't get any files off. I downloaded adb but it does not work in recovery mode.

I ran out of options so I was going to factory reset to fix the restarting bug, and then try to recover the data with an [android recovery tool](https://drfone.wondershare.com/android-data-recovery.html).

Since this is inherently risky, I was hoping that a better option to backup the phone would be provided.

P.S. Its not my phone. I know how to back up XD

Comment: Factory recovery only allow for adb sideloading... Is the bootloader unlocked, if so you could flash TWRP which has a full blown MPT support  and USB-OTG capability and you could copy to a flash drive with a $2 USB-OTG cable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I modified [this script](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/123067/173263) to automate file transfer in between reboots:

```
#!/bin/sh

rfolder=/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/$1
lfolder=$2 
homeDir=`pwd`
adb shell ls "$rfolder" > android.files

ls "$lfolder" -1 > local.files

rm -f update.files
touch update.files

while IFS=  read -r q; do
  # Remove non-printable characters (are not visible on console)
  l=$(echo ${q} | sed 's/[^[:print:]]//')
  # Populate files to update
  if ! grep -q "$l" local.files; then         
    echo "$l" >> update.files
  fi  
done
```

Its slow but it works

Answer (score 0):

You can get your files to your computer through ADB push and pull commands.

Steps to perform this

1. You need to have [Android SDK](http://www.androidauthority.com/how-to-install-android-sdk-software-development-kit-21137/) and [ADB](http://www.androidauthority.com/about-android-debug-bridge-adb-21510/) on your PC.
2. Connect your device to your phone
   and thats it

Now you can use ADB commands to pull data from your phone to your PC.

**Eg.**

**To Pull data from the device you do this**

```
adb pull /sdcard/video.mp4 Users/admin/Desktop
```

Heres a complete step by step Guide on how to transfer files using adb : [link](http://www.androidauthority.com/android-customization-transfer-files-adb-push-adb-pull-601015/)