# adb: Push a folder and add only new files within it

Tags: adb

Using  adb, we can push files or folders. But how can I push a folder ("Music" for example) into my `/sdcard/` that already contains this folder to add just the new files within Music on my computer ? It takes a lot of time to push the entire folder each time I want to add music.

Comment: I don't know how with ADB , but you can see an alternative [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/164437/131553)

Comment: See if this helps: [adb push only if file doesn't exist or has changed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21028394/7551330) and [How to pull only newer files with “adb pull”? (Android SDK utility)](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/40459/209414)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps your best bet is using an alternative tool: [adb-sync](https://github.com/google/adb-sync/tree/master#adb-sync).

> adb-sync is a tool to synchronize files between a PC and an Android
>   device using the ADB (Android Debug Bridge).

**Setup**

Android

- basically you need to allow USB debugging.

PC

> - Install the [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) (the stand-alone Android SDK "for an existing IDE" is sufficient). Alternatively, some Linux distributions
>     come with a package named like "android-tools-adb" that contains the
>     required tool.
> - Make sure "adb" is in your `PATH`.(If you use a package from your Linux distribution, this should already be the case; if you used the
>     SDK, you probably will have to add an entry to PATH in your ~/.profile
>     file, log out and log back in.)
> - `git clone https://github.com/google/adb-sync`
> - `cd adb-sync`
> - Copy or symlink the adb-sync script somewhere in your PATH. For example: `cp adb-sync /usr/local/bin/`

**Usage**

To get a full help, type:

```
adb-sync --help
```

To synchronize your music files from ~/Music to your device, type one of:

```
adb-sync ~/Music /sdcard
adb-sync ~/Music/ /sdcard/Music
```

Additionally you can play around with flags in defined in the help section to get the desired result.

Acknowledgements

- [adb-sync](https://github.com/google/adb-sync/tree/master)

Comment: adb-sync is all written and requires python 3.6+, which made it a no go for me